# How do I run a search query based on recipient in PowerShell for Exchange 2010?

Tags: exchange-2010, powershell

I've tried to run the following commands but neither work and I'm not sure how I should setup the query. I tried to find a full list of available search strings but couldn't locate one online or using help.

I did find the list here (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb232132.aspx#AQS) but it doesn't include the search queries I am looking for (based on the fact that it doesn't even list "Received:" which I know is an option because I use it all the time.

Search-Mailbox -Identity  -SearchQuery 'Received:' 'To:' -LogLevel Full –DeleteContent

Search-Mailbox -Identity  -SearchQuery 'Received:' 'Recipient:' -LogLevel Full –DeleteContent

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a link with the information I needed:

http://unifiedpeople.ru/exch2010help.en/html/cf504a59-1938-489c-bb48-b27b2ac3234e.htm

Proper query for those needing the information in the future is:

Search-Mailbox -Identity  -SearchQuery ' Received:' –DeleteContent

Comment: If you answer your own question, you should still "accept" it so that 1) others see that the question is answered and 2) so that it doesn't get bumped to the front page periodically.